# Can a function be polymorphic and overloaded?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, overload

In Graham Hutton's book "Programming in Haskell", he defines a function to be *polymorphic*, if its type "contains one or more type variables". He then defines a function to be *overloaded*, if its type "contains one or more class constraints".

From these definitions, my question is, "can a function be *polymorphic* and *overloaded*?".

For example, the function `elem` in the standard prelude, essentially has a type of `Eq a => [a] -> Bool`. Can we say that this function is both *polymorphic* and *overloaded*?

EDIT:

Graham Hutton said "Given that class constraints can only be used to type variables, my answer would be yes, a function can be called both polymorphic and overloaded. In particular, any overloaded function is by these definitions also polymorphic. However, I can understand why someone may wish to keep a distinction between these two terms. For the purposes of the book I wanted to have clear and simple definitions."

[Haskell Wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism), states that `elem` is an example of "ad-hoc polymorphism", whilst something like `id :: a -> a`, is an example of "parametric polymorphism".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Following the definition the answer is trivial. If A => B and C => D, then A⋀C => B⋀D

Answer (score 4):

An "overloaded" function has to be polymorphic, because it's impossible to write a class constraint unless the function signature already contains a type variable.  Based on this, I wouldn't say that *overloaded* is a very useful concept in Haskell.